# Force span to act like list indicator

Tags: html, css

**Hey Guys!**

Let me present my problem!

I have a huge table. Cells can be empty, or can contain the following:

`<span>[short text]</span> longer text`

This table is somewhat responsive, the width of the cells may vary on different screens, so the content can be broken into multiple lines. What I want to achieve is to indent the text outside the `<span>`, if it has line breaks. Something like this:

```
[short text] longer text, which is
             broken into two lines
```

I can restructure the table, if it's necessary, to enclose the "long text" in `<span>`-s too, but if you have a smarter solution, I would be up to it.

Comment: I've added an answer with two `span`. It could be without, but to make that work, the short text should have a fixed width... is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by putting the "short text" and "long text" both in a `span` and display them both as `table-cells`:

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td>span {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td>span:first-of-type {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>short text</span>
      <span>long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long text </span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use 2 div instead of

```
<tr><td>
<div id=short style='float:left'>[short text]</div>
<div id=short style='float:left'>[long text]</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `<div>` instead of `<span>`. `word-break: break-all;` can be a good option.

```css
td div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}
.wordwrap {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="wordwrap">
        asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfadvaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="wordwrap">test</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to misunderstood this. Both texts are in the same cell.